# Trying to install NVIDIA drivers, can't find version.h

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 15.10

Alright, so I'm trying to install NVIDIA graphics drivers for my GT610 in order to maybe get my computer to work like a machine with 8 GB of RAM and a 3 GHz AMD CPU should. So, I'm trying to do it the normal way, you know, download the drivers, running `chmod +x <nameofdriver>.run` and then `./<nameofdriver>.run` with X turned off. But that doesn't work. When I try doing that, the installer gives me a couple of errors. First, it tells me that "distribution-provided pre-install script failed! Continue installation anyway?" So I continue. Then it tells me that it can't find version.h and that I need to configure the kernel source files. Of course, I try running the commands recommended in the related questions, such as `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`. But, that doesn't work, because it wants to tell me that I already have the kernel installed. This is, of course, true. I do have *some* of the kernel installed, but apparently not all of it. So, how do I fix this? How do I get version.h?

Kernel is 4.2.0-35-generic, distro is Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: This is not the normal way of installing stuff on Ubunto/debian. Threse distros are known for having own repository of such packages. You need to `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driverVersion` to install nvidia drivers for Your card which were designed to work properly with Your current operating system and kernel version. Please read [THIS ARTICLE](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/) to gain basic knowledge about installing nvidia drivers on Ubuntu distros.

Comment: Alright, here's an issue to try out: the driver that NVIDIA says I need doesn't appear to be installed on my computer, and `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361.42` doesn't work. Yes, I installed the PPA first.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361`

Comment: Please keep in mind its always better to install older, but supported drivers by Ubuntu than jumping to the highest version provided by nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's missing kernel sources specifically. You can fix that by running

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Hope this helps.